# Trouble Enabling HTTPS for Next.js Application in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssl, next.js

I'm facing an issue when trying to enable HTTPS for my Next.js application while debugging it in Visual Studio Code. I'm using the mkcert tool to generate SSL certificates, and the application works fine over HTTP, but I'm unable to get it running over HTTPS.

Problem:

I've generated SSL certificates using mkcert as follows:

```
mkcert -install
mkcert localhost
```

The certificates (localhost.pem and localhost-key.pem) are located in the root directory of my project.

I've also set up the following configuration in my launch.json for the debugger:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "dev", "--", "--port", "3000"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "env": {
        "HTTPS": "true",
        "SSL_CRT_FILE": "./localhost.pem",
        "SSL_KEY_FILE": "./localhost-key.pem"
      },
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, despite having the certificates and using the correct configuration, the application still starts only over HTTP (http://localhost:3000) instead of HTTPS (https://localhost:3000). I've also tried clearing the browser cache and checking the console for errors, but I haven't found a solution.

Question:

1. What could be the reason for the application not starting over HTTPS?
2. Are there any additional steps or configurations I'm missing?
3. How can I troubleshoot this issue further and get my Next.js application to run over HTTPS using the generated SSL certificates?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or advice on how to resolve this issue and successfully enable HTTPS for my Next.js application in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: related?: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10935